# Is the modulus of this complex function a cotinuous funtion in r and t

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be an nth - degree polynomial with given real coefficients.Consider the mod of $p(z)$ for z in the unit disc $|z|\leq 1$ for various $z=re^{it}$ where $0 \leq r\leq 1,0 \leq t\leq 2 \pi$.Is $|p(re^{it})|$ a continuous function of
$ r$ and $t$?

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know what mod p(z) means, but anyway. The function $(r,t)\rightarrow |p(re^it)|$ has to be continuous because it is defined by composing three continuous functions

Comment: That means it takes all the values between its minimum and maximum value.Am I right ?

Comment: It means what I said. It means  the function is continuous

Comment: Ok.I got my point now it will do  so i.e. attain all values between min and max if the min and max values are distinct,by Intermediate Value Theorem